# excludepkgs yum python API

Tags: python, yum

I am trying to write python script to update the packages ( similar to yum update).
Following script enabled 2 repo's ( which I want to use) and then run yum update. Its working fine but I want to exclude some packages ( example any package starts from "kernel*"). I was checking the API yum documentation but didn't find examples. I see that there is function called excludePackages(repo=None) but I am not sure how to pass the lists of packages there or how to use this function.

Can someone please help?

```
#! /usr/env python  
import yum  
import os  
import sys  


yb = yum.YumBase()  
yb.setCacheDir()  
print "Enabled repos are:"  
yb.repos.disableRepo("*")  
for name in ('reponame1','reponame2'):  
  yb.repos.enableRepo(name + ',')  

for repo in yb.repos.listEnabled():  #checking the enabled repos  
   print "%s" %(repo.id)  

yb.update()  
yb.resolveDeps()  
yb.buildTransaction()  
yb.processTransaction()  
yb.processTransaction(rpmDisplay=yum.rpmtrans.NoOutputCallBack())  
yb.doUnlock()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the exclude list per repo, globally or via the command line.

```
repo.setAttribute('exclude', ['kernel*'])
```

## References

- http://yum.baseurl.org/api/yum-3.2.27/yum.repos-pysrc.html#Repository.setAttribute
- http://yum.baseurl.org/api/yum-3.2.27/yum.repos-pysrc.html#Repository.getExcludePkgList
- http://yum.baseurl.org/api/yum-3.2.27/yum-pysrc.html#YumBase.excludePackages

Comment: Thanks a lot . I will try that out!